# How Can I check if both Arrays inside this.state contains same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two Arrays , One contains the index number of correct answer `correctAnswers`

And `userAnswers` contain the index number of answer selected by the user

**How Can I check if Both of them have a same value on the index , If yes then add +1 to the `Total`**

```
    this.state = {
        correctAnswers: [], // [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3]
        userAnswers: [],    // [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3]
        Total: 0
    };
```

So in Above case Total should be `Total =6`

My attempt :

```
const correctAnswers = this.state.correctAnswers;
    const userAnswers = this.state.userAnswers;

    compareAnswers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
        if (correctAnswers[i] === userAnswers[i]) {
            this.setState({ Total: +1 });
        } else console.log("ITS NOT A RIGHT ANSWER ");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to the object you already have:

```js
let state = {
  correctAnswers: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3],
  userAnswers: [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  Total: 0,
  evalScore() {
    this.correctAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        if (answer === this.userAnswers[index]) {
          this.Total++
        }
    })
  }
}

state.evalScore();
console.log(state.Total);
```

You can even use `Total` property for this and make it work like a computed property:

```js
let state = {
  correctAnswers: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3],
  userAnswers: [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  Total() {
    // make sure both array have the same number of elements
    if(this.correctAnswers.length !== this.userAnswers.length) {
      return null;
    }
    let total = 0
    this.correctAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        if (answer === this.userAnswers[index]) {
          total++
        }
    })
    return total
  }
}

console.log(state.Total());
```

#### Edit: Google Chrome Screenshot

[image: Google Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: It just gives me an Error "Cannot read property 'correctAnswers' of undefined"

Comment: When you run the snippet?

Comment: Yes , I have no clue why

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @connexo use IIFE to initialize that total to avoid multiple computations everytime Total() is called.

Comment: I expect you want the ability to call `Total()` multiple times, e.g. if you passed new Arrays into `state.correctAnswers` or `state.userAnswers`, and do a proper recomputation each time.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Me too. Added a screenshot showing the output I'm getting.

Comment: Thats strange , maybe i need to upgrade my browser

Comment: I am running Version 64.0.3282.186 (64 bit) on MacOS.

Comment: Could you solve your browser problem for running my snippets?

Comment: One thing is there a way if the value !== I can have the value of the index and not value itself ?

Comment: I don't get what you want?

Comment: Does not matter got it sorted out , Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, since it's an array inside of an object, and the actual object has a `this` reference, we have to accommodate that.

```
  for(var i=0;i<this.state.correctAnswers.length;i++){
  if(this.state.correctAnswers[i] === this.state.userAnswers[i]){
    this.state.Total++;
  }
}
```

Using this method, we can dynamically compare both arrays. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt looks good, except that it has a syntax error (you can't do `Total: +1` like that). Instead you could use the functional `setState` syntax, which for your snippet would look like:

```
compareAnswers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
        if (correctAnswers[i] === userAnswers[i]) {
            this.setState(oldState => ({...oldState, Total: oldState.Total++}));
        } else console.log("ITS NOT A RIGHT ANSWER ");
    }
}
```

*However, it would probably be better to batch all the sums and only set the state once when we're done*, which would look like:

```
compareAnswers() {
    let newTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
        if (correctAnswers[i] === userAnswers[i]) {
            newTotal++;
        } else console.log("ITS NOT A RIGHT ANSWER ");
    }

    this.setState({Total: newTotal})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt based on assumption that all the questions are mandatory and would be answered sequentially by the user:

```
compareAnswer() {
    // Addressing the best case i.e. when all user answers are correct
    if (JSON.stringify(this.state.correctAnswers) == JSON.stringify(this.state.userAnswers)) {
           this.setState({ Total: this.state.correctAnswers.length });
    } else {
           for (var i=0; i<this.state.userAnswers.length; i++) {
               if (this.state.correctAnswers[i] === this.state.userAnswers[i]) {
                  this.setState({ Total: this.state.Total++ });
               }
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` and a ternary condition:

```
state.Total += (c === state.correctAnswers[i] ? 1 : 0)
```

```js
var state = {
  correctAnswers: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3],
  userAnswers: [1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  Total: 0
};

state.userAnswers.forEach((c, i) => state.Total += (c === state.correctAnswers[i] ? 1 : 0));

console.log(state)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why `Array.prototype.forEach.call(state.userAnswers` on a native Array?

Comment: `[].forEach` is bad practice.

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/#problem-4-creates-a-needless-array

Comment: Why not simply `state.userAnswers.forEach((c, i) => state.Total += (c === state.correctAnswers[i] ? 1 : 0));)`?